# Command line tool to get binary data as String in Windows like Cat?

Tags: c, windows, pipe, stdin, cat

So I have program that transforms data by piping the string into stdin like so.

```
cat input.mp3 | myexe
```

except I want this commandline tool to run on Windows.

```
type input.mp3 | myexe.exe
```

and cat and type provide different inputs because of how Windows treat binary files according to the question that referred to me to use cat. So how can I have a more a faithful representation of cat on Windows? Or is there a way I can the input from cat in pure C? Any help would be appreciated.

Update: Here is my code
https://github.com/Skylion007/LVDOWin

forked and ported from:
https://github.com/m13253/lvdo

I've modified the argument parsing slightly in my own code (only get-opt not get-opt-long), other than that I am using the same command line statements of the readme in the later repo. I would post the code here, but there is a lot a fluf and I don't want overwhelm an already complex answer.

```
type hello.mp3 | lvdoenc.exe -s 640x480 -q 6 -b8 | x264 --input-res 640x480 --fps 1 --profile high --level 5.1 --tune    stillimage --crf 22 --colormatrix bt709 --me dia --merange 0 -o public.mkv -
```

is an example of a command I used to encode the file initially. On Linux, I would use cat.

Comment: Take a look at unxutils (http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) for Windows versions of cat and other utilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just redirect input from the file this way:

```
myexe < input.mp3
```

and force `stdin` to binary mode at the beginning of the `main` function in `myexe` this way:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), O_BINARY);
```

You may need to add or remove underscores depending on your tools version.

The text mode versus binary mode is a Windows oddity inherited from the dark ages of microcomputing. It goes back all the way to the 1970s, from a popular pre-MSDOS operating system called CP/M from which is was copied. Unix and all its variants never had this and Apple ditched its non-standard end of line scheme a long time ago. You are unlikely to run you code on old mainframes which had their own weird notion on line based text files.

Comment: How do I set stdin to binary mode isn't that done in a header file? Also, would that affect the deployment of this code on other operating systems?

Comment: Update, setting the mode to binary and using the < does not seem to work. It still only encodes the header format

Comment: What to you mean by *encodes the header format*?  Post your code, the intended behaviour and the unexpected results.

Comment: @Skylion, how do you output the result? If it's to `stdout` and should be binary, you'll also need `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), O_BINARY)`. If you're outputting to a file, is it open in binary mode, e.g. `"wb"`?

Comment: @eryksun Hmm, I am not sure GCC even will allow me to set the mode? I am using GCC to cross compile this tool from Linux so how should I do this? Can I do so using only the MACRO? Would it even recognize the proper MACRO commands?

Comment: @Skylion: not gcc related, its a header file / C library issue.

Comment: @Skylion: I looked at your code, where do you set the mode for `stdin` and `stdout` to binary?

Comment: @chqrlie Sorry, I haven't pushed those changes yet. Otherwise, the code is the same. I will try to set it outside the MACRO using the other question I asked and see if that helps.